# Firefox Addon SDK: How to add Navigation Toolbar button and drop-down menu

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Developing a `Firefox Add-on`. Please someone help to add a drop-down menu with Navigation Toolbar button (like: `firebug`, `colorzilla`). I'm a newbie in this field.

I've attached a screen-shot to show what I exactly want:

[image]

Comment: This link may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659221/how-to-add-a-dropdown-menu-to-a-firefox-addon-sdk-powered-addon-toolbar-button

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Look here where sdk says there's no sdk-method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Add_a_Menu_Item_to_Firefox