# How do I create an options popup dialog using firefox addon sdk?

Tags: javascript, dialog, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

So I decided recently to create a **firefox extension** I have been thinking about, but do not have any prior experience with it. I read on the official tutorials and figured that the **addons sdk** seemed to fit me well, but I seem to have hit a hitch using it.

What I want to do is create an **options popup dialog**, similar to the one you see if you press [**alt-tools-options**](http://cnet3.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/2011/03/13/50780ecc-fdba-11e2-8c7c-d4ae52e62bcc/64af04c5bb514a1a5e22cee21bdfdcd3/03_14_11_Firefox_cookies_2.jpg). That is, a border with title and close button on the upper part, and a bigger area inside the window where I can define an "intuitive" (default elements with the skin the user is used to) GUI.
The tabs at the top (general, privacy security etc.) is nothing I really need, though would not hurt either.

So the issue is that from my searches, when you use addon sdk, you are not supposed to use XUL which has those elements, but instead you seem to be supposed to create something custom using **[HTML in a panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Display_a_Popup)**. I don't think its possible to create the top-bar akin to the real options-menu when using that, although if I am wrong I would not mind being corrected.

I had a similar issue before, where I wanted a drop-down menu from the toolbar similar to the default ones, which I solved thanks to: [How to add a dropdown menu to a firefox addon sdk powered addon toolbar button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659221/how-to-add-a-dropdown-menu-to-a-firefox-addon-sdk-powered-addon-toolbar-button).
Might be worth noting that that the button opening the options dialog is one of the menuitems created as described there.
I was considering that it could probably be possible (aka I am not sure) to use something akin to this, but sadly I do not know how I would create a "separate" (drag-able) popup that I could use this on.

If possible, I would prefer there to exist a solution, but if someone knows that it is indeed impossible, please do post that so and I can give up without regrets and just make some sort of custom HTML panel instead :)

tldr:
Is there a way to create a popup dialog similar (in style) to the options window you can open using alt-tools-options in firefox when developing using addon sdk?

Comment: I don't understand what popup dialog you mean. How do you open it?

Comment: If you have firefox in focus, try pressing the key **alt**. This will bring up the familiar *file, edit, ... , tools, help* buttons at the top left of the window. When you select **tools** there will exist a menuitem called **options**. Select it and the popup dialog appears. If you want to use keyboard only, the key-combination is **Alt-T-O**. If you press the link **alt-tools-options** in OP you will also see a screenshot of it.

Comment: What OS are you using? I'm using a Mac, that doesn't apply at all to what I'm seeing.

Comment: Ah, I use windows. I dont know how one would open it in mac, but a quick google suggests this might work https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/what-happened-to-the-file-edit-and-view-menus?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Menu+bar+is+missing#os=mac and I just now noticed that for me (and in the images on that link), there is an options item in that menu before you select customize that opens it as well

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you aren't supposed to, at least not with the SDK.

But then again, it is still possible, but you need to do a lot of stuff yourself:

1. You need to register a `chrome:` package for your add-on, as the `resource:` URIs the SDK uses internally do not work correctly for XUL windows. Create a [Chrome Registration](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Chrome_Registration) (`chrome.manifest` file). The SDK supports this since Firefox 24 IIRC.
2. Create the XUL file. For preferences/options windows, there is already the [`<prefwindow>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/prefwindow) binding. Look at other extensions and or the [Firefox Options dialog](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/components/preferences/) (which is a *huge* thing with multiple overlays, so better look at other extensions). Place the XUL file in `chrome/content/<somefile>.xul`. This will then correspond to `chrome://<registered_package_from_1>/content/<somefile>.xul`.
3. Implement something that will actually display the window. Normally non-SDK add-ons would just put `em:optionsURL` into their `install.rdf`, to have the Add-On Manager automatically create a Preferences button that will open the specified URL, but in the SDK this is generated from `package.json` and there is no way to put `optionsURL` in `package.json` if I'm not mistaken. But you could do other things, like using a `simple-prefs` `type: control` button to have a button in your `about:addons` page, or add it to some browser menu (which would require yet another heap of XUL-modifying, `require("chrome")` code.). To actually open the dialog, you could use [`window/utils.openDialog`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/window_utils#openDialog%28options%29).
4. Don't forget to close any open windows again when your add-on gets unloaded.

As you can see, not a simple task...
If you're just after preferences in general, consider using [`simple-prefs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs).

Comment: Thanks, havent had time to try it out yet, but it definitely looks promising. Will return to here and post my results once I tried it out. Seen the *simple-prefs* before, but as far as I can tell I wont be able to do what I want in it, since I am going to need to display the users list of 'subscriptions' with the ability to add/edit them (the user tells the plugin to create any number of what I call 'subscriptions': essentially just an url, a html tags class and a regex. The regex is performed on those tags outerHTML periodically, and if the result changed, the user is notified).

Comment: So after trying what you said, I seem to have gotten it to work for the most part. Thanks for the help! Just a few things I think is worth mentioning in case someone stumbled upon this thread in the future: The link in **#1** helped me a lot, but the **content** command in the chrome.manifest need to be written `content packagename chrome/content/pathtofiles/` (as in the **"chrome/"** part is needed). I was stuck for quite a while because I did not know that :P. Character_limit, continuing in the next comment...

Comment: Another thing worth mentioning is that I never got **OpenDialog** to work, and in the end had to use **Open** instead (`var winUtils2 = require('sdk/window/utils'); var dialog = winUtils2.open("chrome://custom_options/content/options.xul", "", "");`). Now I just need to figure out how to make **self.port** work or find another way to send data back to the original script, and this question will be solved. Luckily, I suspect that [Passing_data_between_windows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code#Passing_data_between_windows) will help me with that.